# Gradle sync failed access is denied in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Can someone please explain to me what this error is and how to resolve this error?

> Gradle sync failed: D:\SoundsandPictures.gradle\4.4\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock (Access is denied)

Note: My project was on D: drive and i accidently deleted all my data on the drive  and recovered it using a recovery software and getting this error while opening the project in android studio.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Goto File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Shutdown Android Studio

Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory

Restart Android Studio (It will download gradle metadata and data)

Gradle build succeed

Rebuild project. Done.

**EDIT**

Try this for Mac OS

Go to SDK manager (with Administrator rights), scroll down till the end, download "Android Support Library".

And it works (don't forget Administrator rights).

Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847693/android-studio-0-8-2-gradle-project-sync-failed) SO Question..

Comment: It's not working bro and what do you mean by all project files.

Comment: Now where are the files stored after recovery

Comment: I stored all the files in a seperate folder in the other drive and just copy and pasted the project in D:

Comment: The problem here is administrator permission, i don't  know why but this time in d: drive it is asking for administrator permission every time when i copy paste or delete something. So i thing this issue is different and all solutions provided by you are correct. Now i am using my project in the E drive and it's not giving that access denied error but because of recovery software some of my java file text got converted into special symbols like this '肙ⱉ鳪⽛芨̆ഋ垦'

Comment: gr8 it worked.. thata the reason i asked to ensure that all your project files were recovered during recovery....

Comment: What about MacOs. I have the same problem, what gradle folder should i remove?

Comment: Do you care to explain why it fixes it? It is like demolishing and re-building a house to repair its window!

Answer (score 5):

If do you have an antivirus software, try to check if it has blocked Android Studio.

[image: BitDefender did block my AndroidStudio]

Comment: Was the issue for me (using BitDefender Internet Security)

Comment: Worked! Windows defender acts very weird sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I hid the .gradle file. On unhiding the file, it was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, but
I was getting the error "caches\5.1.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)",
deleting that file and re-building the project worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

/.gradle/4.6/fileChanges/last-build.bin%20(Access%20is%20denied)

I resolved this issue by deleting .gradle folder and then restart android studio 
clean and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

i deleted the file, then appear another message but with other file, i did the same 3 times, and then a clean and rebuild and worked.
PS: those files regenerate after the build, so no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Same error was showing while doing in vs code. I solved just by deleting this   .gradle\caches\6.1.1\file-changes\last-build.bin file. After relaunching the vscode the problem wa

Answer (score 0):

make files not hidden (unchiek hidden in windows)

Answer (score 0):

it means that you have no right to access that file, in my case it was on *.jar files at c:\gradle subfolders so I solve it by cmd:

C:\icacls "[PathToYourDeniedFilesOrFolderLikeC:\gradle]" /grant [YourWindowsUserNameHereLikeUser]:(OI)(CI)F /T

if it did not work you can right click on that file go to security tab then add yourself to get full permission on it. Good Luck Coding . . .

Hope this Helps ^_^

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In macOS I faced the same issue, the issue was that I moved this project and it was set as read-only.

I just had to run this command to allow read and write to fix this.

`sudo chmod -R +rwX myProject`

Answer (score -1):

OK.. To solve this issue, simple navigate to your project folder like  C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\Project.gradle\taskArtifacts folder and delete the file. The fileHashes.lock is holding a global lock and is preventing you from running your script. Deleting the folder would create the file again and your project will get built. Also there is a possibility that there are other locked files. Simply delete everything within the C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches folder.

Comment: Not working , i have tried it and now it is saying failed to create directory 'D:\soundsandpictures\.gradle\4.4\fileHashes

Comment: I also want to add one more thing here is when i start the android studio it starts with a popup  'Failed to save setting. please restart android studio.'

Comment: after following the above procedure  do this once again... Goto File -> Invalidate caches / Restart Shutdown Android Studio .. then do Build->Clean Project and also Build Project.. to create the deleted file once again..

Answer (score -1):

Create a new Android project and move all your recovered files into it. This issue you are facing is because of existing settings in the old project.

Then ...

Go to File--> Project Structure --> Check Use Embedded JDK (Recommended)[image: Check Use Embedded JDK]

Answer (score -1):

whenever this happens 
JUST DEL (MAKE A BACKUP 1ST) THE CULPRIT FILE (THE FILE RIGHT BEFORE THE MSG "ACCESS IS DENIED"

hope this helps