# Android studio build failed with "access is denied" and "Failed to create parent directory"

Tags: android

I had this problem:

> access is denied.

Then I tried this solution: [build failed, access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992542/gradle-sync-failed-access-is-denied-in-android-studio)

I followed the instructions. But, after restarting Android studio, I got this message:

> Failed to create parent directory
>   'C:\Users\safayat\Documents\MyFirstApp.gradle' when creating
>   directory
>   'C:\Users\safayat\Documents\MyFirstApp.gradle\4.10.1\fileHashes'

Comment: Do you have write permissions for `C:\Users\safayat\Documents`? i.e. can you create a new folder there in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Yes, I have the permission.