# fileHashes.lock (Access is denied)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting this error while building the apk: **.gradle\4.6\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock (Access is denied)**
I had tried all the possibilities mentioned in [Gradle sync failed access is denied in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992542/gradle-sync-failed-access-is-denied-in-android-studio/50992647)

Apart from deleting **.gradle** folder, I had also tried to move **.gradle** folder to another drive but didn't resolved my error. I had also uninstalled and again installed Android Studio but no more modifications.

Answer (score 4):

For my case, I solved this problem by giving permissions to the project folder and its subfolders.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ProjectFolder
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30025627)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue. changing permissions on gradle folder worked out for me.
chmod 755 gradle