# Gradle project sync failed without Messages, worked on command-line

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

In Android Studio, the sync failed:

> Gradle project sync failed.  Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

The command-line `gradle installDebug` worked. There were no messages in the "Messages" view. In the `idea.log`, the following `NullPointerException` appeared:

```
2018-02-04 14:53:15,233 [ thread 15]   WARN - ea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask - Sync failed: null 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator.invokeAndWait(LaterInvocator.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:680)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:685)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeOnEdt(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:469)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.dispose(ProjectDataManager.java:401)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:198)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:204)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.doSelectiveImport(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:206)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populate(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:156)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.access$000(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask$1.run(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.disposeArea(Extensions.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleImpl.dispose(ModuleImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer$1.execute(Disposer.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer$1.execute(Disposer.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeActionWithRecursiveGuard(ObjectTree.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeUnregistered(ObjectTree.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleManagerImpl$ModuleModelImpl.dispose(ModuleManagerImpl.java:836)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.dispose(AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.java:421)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager$3.execute(ProjectDataManager.java:404)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.DisposeAwareProjectChange.run(DisposeAwareProjectChange.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.lambda$null$6(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1023)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.lambda$executeProjectChangeAction$7(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:303)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:410)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:399)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:655)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2018-02-04 14:53:15,234 [ thread 15]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed (4s 121ms)
```

[Using `Invalidate Caches/Restart` and removing the `.gradle` folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808199/error-running-android-gradle-project-sync-failed-please-fix-your-project-and-t) did not help. Why is this? How is it fixed?

Comment: if you do this from the cmd prompt what happens and is installDebug one of the task? gradle tasks --all

Comment: @Pomagranite: yes, it is one of the tasks, it compiles successfully and wants to install to an emulator (which was not attached then). gradle tasks contains "installDebug - Installs the Debug build."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After unsetting a local gradle distribution in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle (which was set for debugging this problem), Android Studio offered to update to `gradle:3.0.1` from `gradle:3.0.0`. This fixed it.

Previous steps taken:

- add the `google()` repository to `buildscript` and `allprojects`
- upgrade the     `compileSdkVersion`,   and      `targetSdkVersion` to 27
- upgrade all `com.android.support` libraries to `26.1.0`

Comment: I figured it was not your code causing the problem as the stack trace does not have any indication of the null belonging to your package. Thanks for posting the answer

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar errors after I upgraded my Android Studio to 3.1.3. I don't remember the exact version I was on before that -- version 2 series.

The reason I was getting these errors was because the Gradle plugin version I was using was too low.

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    ...
}
```

Once I updated the version from `2.2.3` to `2.3.3`, then Android Studio was able to move on and give me more meaningful error messages such as

> Gradle sync failed: Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip

From there, it's just a matter of resolving version compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was a simple solution: I had deleted a module from my project and forgot to delete it from `settings.gradle`

Maybe this can help somebody