# After Android studio upgrade to 3.2 error appears startup failed: initialization script '/tmp/ijinit.gradle'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.2

After upgrading from 3.1 to 3.2 Gradle build is failed with error

```
Cause: startup failed:
initialization script '/tmp/ijinit.gradle': 3: unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
   ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your gradle version to latest version.

Change gradle version to **4.6** from `gradle-wrapper.properties` file for android studio 3.2.

OR

Select Project structure and then project and update gradle version like below:
[image]

Also make sure your project build.gradle dependency are updated:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

If this still doesn't help follow this steps 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38928660/4553806

Comment: Check your build.gradle of project: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0' should be like this.

Comment: Try deleting your project `.gradle` file and build again.

Comment: Do you mean build.gradle(Project:projectName)?

Comment: .gradle folder from your project directory. Its hidden some os in that case you have to make it visible and then delete.

Comment: I tried it, it builds gradle folder again, but error still exists