# Android build.gradle ERROR: ParseError at [row,col]:[65,9] Message: expected start or end tag Affected Modules: app

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

build.gradle:

[image: build.gradle]

Android build.gradle shows following error

```
ERROR: ParseError at [row,col]:[65,9] Message: expected start or end tag Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: Please show us the code. At least around row 65, where the error occurred.

Comment: share your build.gradle file

Comment: @Geshode

Please click on the link above for build.gradle. I have uploaded the image with build.gradle by editing the question. Please check and answer.

Answer (score 66):

I got the same error, and the wrong character was found in the [row, col] position of the AndroidManifest.xml, not build.gradle

Comment: they are really geniuses for doing this to us, but you're the real one.

Comment: Thank you so much man. It's been 8 days almost. Couldn't understand what the error is in build.gradle.

Comment: [row, col] position wasn't correct for me, so don't lock yourself up on that position. But the error was found in the AndroidManifest, so I would strongly suggest to check the syntax there.

Comment: Thanks for saving my Day.

Answer (score 15):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

For me was because I inserted layout width in the layout view from a xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You're my savor! 
Idk why Android Studio throw such an exception without telling which part of the xml getting wrong lol

Comment: Damnnnn!!! @ali6e7, I want to upvote your answer 100000000 times but sorry I can't, I was struggling for 3 days and finallllly some testy food bro.......... +1

Answer (score 12):

I got this same error, and finally I found that there is error in Mainfest.xml file

```
 <service
        android:name=".onboarding.httpserver.HttpService"
        android:exported="false"
        >
    </service>>
```

you see, there are two >> after /service. which is wrong. 
After I fix this error, this message is disappear

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error similar one like

```
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app
[row, cal] 17,17
```

I forget an unnecessary `/>` characters in Manifest. Try to clean if any one has it.

Comment: can you give an example for I may be getting the same thing, but when I tried that, it just created a different error.

Comment: @j.hull main issue is there is some unwanted character in your Manifest try to find it,  if the are row and cal on the messages so numbers are given try to see them

Answer (score 7):

In my project i have made two mistakes that are

1. Extra `>` in manifest file
2. There are some errors in my XML file as in image [image]

so go to Analyse> Inspect Code> to find the problems

Comment: Nice! first time i found inspect code useful!

Answer (score 5):

I got a **Commented line** in manifest file, when i removed the commented line and build the gradle file then the error is solved.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error after updating the Gradle version, Manifest file was the same though. However reformatting the code in Manifest fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

when say `[27:15]` that means you have an error in that position . go to the `27th line` and if you have any `wrong character` correct it or maybe forget the `/>` or any little mistake in your `manifest.xml`

**NOTE: some times the `Merged Manifest` can help you.**

Answer (score 2):

```
Simple answer see any thing by mistakenly added unwanted code in the manifest.xml file.

if manifest.xml file is not visible in the android studio project
Goto project folder choose the manifest.xml file and cross check unwanted or commented code.
```

Answer (score 2):

i added this line twice by mistake:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"


 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong comment syntax.

Please remove the `#` comment from the Manifest file and replace it with `<!-- Comment -->`.

Answer (score 1):

check any unwanted characters that are added in the manifest file by mistake. After removing those characters/lines the problem was solved in my working application. check once and happy coding

Answer (score 1):

also had the same error. just look at the location [row] at the **Manifest** file and fix the problem (I had extra ">")

Answer (score 1):

It usually happens when there is mistakenly if you have entered any **special character or alphabets or numbers** in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Here meaning `[row,col]:[65,9]`  error in line number between `64 to 66`

**In my case it happenen because as I shown in below screen shot**

[image]

Here meaning `[row,col]:[65,9]`  error in line number between `64 to 66`
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In my layout file I accidentally put `android:padding="16dp"` in data binding layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:padding="16dp"  <-----this cause the error in my case
>
.............
..............
..........
</layout>
```

after removing  `android:padding="16dp"` work fine

Comment: This fix it for me, after adding new fragment, then changing from FrameLayout to layout, removing attributes in layout fix it for me (layout only need xmlns attributes). So, if you have xml parser error, check the most recent change from added or remove things from the xml files.

Answer (score 1):

for me, I got this error when I forgot to add

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

in my XML layout

Answer (score 1):

For me it's fixed when I am deleted these 2 lines.[image: You should delete width and height]

It did fixed for me when I do that. Hope you will solve with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find these issues with **Analyse -> Inspect code**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The common steps to spot and fix the error are:

1. Check what files have been changed in this commit.
2. Go through each file and check [row,col] or [row-1] position.
3. Find out which file caused the error and fix it.

In my case the error was

```
ParseError at [row,col]:[2,6]
Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

I spotted the error in my **drawable/background.xml** file which looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inset="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/card_view_corner_radius" />
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorActionDialogBackground" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

**Error**: the first line was empty.

**Fix**: remove the first empty line, so the first line in the xml file should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file I commented like

```
/* something i wrote here
*/
```

When i deleted this commented line then it was synced and run properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like those kind of errors are general and even if they pinpoint the location of the error, they don't mention in which file the error occurs.

A good way to resolve this error is to check inside the latest .xml files you modified.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace The ic_launcher_Background and ic_launcher Foreground
with the correct Code..

Also Check with the Midmap Images if they have some kind of mistake in the XML Code
and Replace them with the Correct Code..

I Will Provide the More Detailed Answer With XML Complete Code If Anyone Finds It Useful...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Firebase Remote config and i found there's issue with locally stored xml for remote_config, "remote_config_local.xml" value json.

Answer (score 0):

It is a late reply, but it may help others.
I faced the same issue, and I resolved it by replacing
`<activity android:name=".Palmsdetail"></activity>` in AndroidManifest.xml with `<activity android:name=".Palmsdetail"/>` the warning is removed and compiled successfully.
Only by closing the tag with `/>` helped.