# Gradle Project Sync Failed after updating to Android Studio 3.3.0

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I haven't touched my Android Studio for a loooong time, it still worked fine when I launched it, but then I updated to 3.3.0 and I get a 'gradle project sync failed'. I know this is not trivial to debug via SO, but I tried to find anything similar and I lack of knowledge about the entire studio didn't help.

So maybe you can guide me to a solution, I'm not sure what files are necessary, but here is the actual error:

> ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\roberts\AndroidProjects\LingoFlash\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
>   ParseError at [row,col]:[27,9]
>   Message: expected start or end tag
>   Affected Modules: app

This is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 20     <application
 21         android:allowBackup="true"
 22         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 23         android:label="@string/app_name"
 24         android:supportsRtl="true"
 25         android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
 26         //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 27         <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
 28             <intent-filter>
 29                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 30                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 31             </intent-filter>
 32         </activity>
```

so what's wrong at line 27? seems to point to the MainActivity

before I paste a ton of data, what would help to debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments in xml files do not start with Double slash `//` they work with `<!--Your comments-->`. Your manifest is having lines that start with `//` remove them and try to clean and build your project.

Comment: ahh, D'OH ! Not only did I have that, but I had totally wrong XML syntax later in the file. HOWEVER, this all did work (and still works on a different machine) with the older 3.2 Studio Version, so something changed in 3.3 (which is probably a good thing). Thanks !

Comment: Did the same mistake. Couldn't found the solution until see this answer. Great

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some wrong character found in the **[27,9]** position of the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52932622/8034839