# ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'myApp' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to try out Android Studio. 
I have a fresh installation on Ubuntu Linux.

When I create new project 
File->New->New Project...

Some files are created and I get error

> ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'myApp'
>   of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: I ran out of disk space while installing studio. So gradle did not install correctly.

I solved my issue following this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38928660/4999870

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it in this mode:

1) Go to File;

2) Invalidate Caches/Restart...

3) Click on Just Restart...

Now go on explorer:

1) this PC/Local Disk/Users/user

2) now delete the folder called: ".gradle"

3) Launch Android Studio

4) Wait for uploads

5) And now click sync

It will probably give you an error, click on written underlined in blue under the error, and wait;

FINISH

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the caches files in the `.gradle` folder is corrupted and needed an update. the best way is to delete cache file in your `.gradle` folder.

Steps:

1. Delete caches folder in the `.gradle` folder "You can find it on Mac /Users//.gradle"
2. Go to File and Invalidate Caches/Restart
3. AS will restart and the build should now Sync.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Go to build.gradle
2. dependencies classpath
3. Click classpath suggestion then
4. Click Invoke upgrade assistant for upgrade to 4.2.2