# I am unable to perform a successful project sync with my Android Studio project

Tags: android, gradle

I am unable to get my Android Studio to work properly when I create an empty Activity project. I get the error messages below;

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 915 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/private/var/folders/01/1rsv7cx936b4fsv29ttwnr6w0000gn/T/sync.studio.tooling.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'SSGCodingChallenge' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'SSGCodingChallenge' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated. I am really stuck with this since it has been a good couple of years since I touched Android Studio.

Comment: I think you have the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/q/59422617/5531164

Comment: @frumle OK thanks. I think it happened because my mac ran out of disk space part way through downloading an update to Kotlin. Installing on my windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Installed on my Windows machine instead.