# Android Studio Update Gradle Issue

Tags: android, chipmunk

I just upgraded Android Studio to Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 and afterwards my gradle sync attempts are failing and I cannot debug my app any longer???

Getting:

```
7:12 AM Gradle sync needed
Project was built with Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 7.2.0 but it is synced with .
Please sync the project with Gradle Files.
Sync project
```

When I sync I get:

```
7:17 AM Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown
```

I have:
Cleaned project
Deleted the .gradle folder then invalidated / restarted.
Used AGP tool which said all was updated.

Anybody else having this issue with the upgrade?

Thank you

Comment: I have upgraded my Android studio but not getting issue May be this will helps you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808199/error-running-android-gradle-project-sync-failed-please-fix-your-project-and-t

Comment: I have updated 2 line with previous path gradle-wrapper.properties -> 
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip  and build.gradle(app level) -->     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Deleting the .idea and cache folders solved mine then clean and rebuild project will generate new gradle**

Comment: That was it! Removed the .idea folder!

Comment: Appreciate the help! May never upgrade AS again :-)

Comment: Invalidate Caches and Restart worked for me!!!